# How to find out the availability of datatype in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, types

Is there any way to find out particular datatype [say for example chkpass] is available or not through a query ?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL provides a huge amount of meta-data which is easily accessed via SQL. To obtain information about the presence of a (scalar) data type, the information provided by [pg_type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/catalog-pg-type.html) catalog might be of interest here. Try, for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM pg_type
WHERE typname = 'chkpass'
```

Answer (score 0):

run: psql -E

and then, in psql session \dT or \dTS